# How to create and get started with Embedded Apache Derby database in Dropwizard project (Angular 7 front-end)

Tags: database, rest, http, derby, dropwizard

I'm reading through Derby documentation and following all the instructions. I've successfully installed it (extracted it to my Linux machine and set the DERBY_HOME path). I have a complete REST API project with Angular 7 front-end and Dropwizard backend. I hard coded some data in the backend, and created all the HTTP API methods I need (GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE).

The application is fully functional, but now I need to implement the Embedded version of Derby into it. I have 0 experience with such databases, and because Dropwizard gave me enough trouble already, I cannot figure out how to get started.

Do I create a new class and get started there, how to create those SQL files and how to store data? I can't find a concrete answer to similar questions, if there are detailed explanations and examples already out there, please feel free to provide me with the resources. I know this is a noob question, but I just barely learned how HTTP works (the basics) and managed to completely create a functional REST using Angular and Dropwizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the embedded database like a full-fledged database, that instead of being in a different environment, and maybe requiring a network connection, is packed along with your application and run in the same JVM. The same mechanisms applies between the two.

The embedded Derby Driver is located inside the `derby.jar` file, so it is required to have it in the *classpath* of your application. It should be located under `%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\`, where `%DERBY_INSTALL%` is the installation directory. You can see by the image where it is contained.

[image]

From [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html)

> Any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your class path are
>   automatically loaded. (However, you must manually load any drivers
>   prior to JDBC 4.0 with the method Class.forName.)

What that means is that if the Derby driver is a JDBC 4.0 driver, you don't have to do anything else besided getting a connection via `DriverManager`.
If it is not a JDBC 4.0 driver, you'll have to instantiate the Driver with

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
```

Appartently you'll need that piece of code above.
Now simply get a hold on a `Connection` object.

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:dbName;create=true");
```

From there on, you can create `Statement`(s) as you like. Which means you can create tables, insert rows, update rows, delete rows, etc.

To gracefully shutdown the embedded Derby database, you need to use

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:dbName;shutdown=true"); // see the same database name "dbName"
```

prior to quitting the main application. It is not mandatory, but recommended.

---

You can create a utility class to hold an `EmbeddedDataSource` ([docs](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/publishedapi/org/apache/derby/jdbc/EmbeddedDataSource.html)), which will provide connections around your application.

```
public final class EmbeddedDerby {
   private static final DataSource DATA_SOURCE;

   static {
      // Initialize DATA_SOURCE with EmbeddedDataSource
   }

   ...

   public static Connection getConnection() {
     return DATA_SOURCE.getConnection();
   }
}
```

Comment: Alright, Where do I input that code? Do I create a new class besides my Menu and Order classes? I downloaded the Derby (10.14.2 bin) and unpacked it. I also declared the $DERBY_HOME path in the bash. Do I just simply create another class called Derby besides the ones I already have and enter the class.forName piece of code. Also, do I add the getConnection method in one of my existing classes?

Comment: Alright buddy I'll give it a shot in 12hrs approx. What I'll do is create the EmbeddedDerby class and copy the code you gave me at the end of your response. I'm struggling with official explanations, and when you tell explain to me what to do in simple words like copy this file inside that folder, it makes it a lot easier to understand, that's how I managed to finish the dropwizard part, I implemented two additional PATCH methods, thanks to your example. The " required to have it in the classpath of your application", does that mean I should copy the file to where my other classes are?

Comment: @soulzap not really. You know that a Java application has the concept of classpath, the place where the JVM looks for .class files. The location to put the JAR under depends on the enviroment. For example, if you're using a web server, maybe they have to go under WEB-INF/lib, if it is an executable standalone application maybe add the JAR via -cp commandline parameter, or via Manifest. You need to take car of this bit alone I think

Comment: that's alright, I'll figure it out for sure. Do I create the statements in the same ËmbeddedDerby class where I initialize the DATA SOURCE. And could you please provide me with only one example how would I call that statement (or create it) for the, let's say, get or post methods? I know how to create the functions and call them, which will send data to the client and vice versa, but i'm kinda struggling to figure out how exactly is my backend going to communicate with the embedded database and send that data to the user or add new data based on the user's input.

Comment: @soulzap I will, don't worry. I'm out now so I can't

Comment: Alright buddy, counting on you, as always. I think this is the last step before I deploy my rest api online, after which I'll most likely find out whether I'm getting my first job or not. I'll be thankful for the rest of my life for all your input, regardless of the outcome.

Comment: I'm kinda struggling with the classpath part, but i'll get it to work somehow. Could you please explain to me in simple words where do I write the code you gave me? Do I create a new class next to my models, or does it go in the Main.java? :/

Comment: @soulzap everything (or almost everything) of the Embedded Driver initialization and shutdown should go inside the class I added above. But you shouldn't have to manually do it. Look at the EmbeddedDataSource. You just set the DB name, and you're good to go. https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/publishedapi/org/apache/derby/jdbc/EmbeddedDataSource.html

Comment: @soulzap in the page I linked there is an example, look down. Anyway don't panick, go slowly and try to understand what you're doing

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code, so i'm in a bit of trouble when it comes to this stuff. Any other tips or help please? I spent the entire night researching and the only two things I could think of are not working... I just can't understand in simple words how to get started :( I'll get the statements later on my own

Comment: @soulzap I don't know what else to write. Once you have your EmbeddedDerby class set up, you just need to use it around your application, something like "final Connection connection = EmbeddedDerby.getConnection();"

Comment: Hey. I've managed to get things going somehow and I have created the database successfully. There are a couple of issues but I'll handle them myself. Please tell me one thing - do I have to change the existing repository and resource classes to get the app to pull data form a database, or do all the statements go into the DBConnector class i created? Like do I just have to use (at)SQLUpdate when creating functions in repository and resource files?

Comment: @soulzap how does the existing repository works now? I mean, does it accept a Connection? Or how does it connect to a database?

Comment: public class DBConnector   {



    public static Connection createDatabaseConnection()

    throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
            String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
            Class.forName(driver);
             String url = "jdbc:derby:FOADB";
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url+";create=true");
            return c;
            }
}

This is what I did, it created a database. I also edited the yml file. What do you recon i should do next?

@LppEdd

Comment: sorry for pasting code like that, something's screwed up so I can't edit it properly, but yeah. The database was created but I have no idea how to talk to the db now. Everything was working now even the localhost:8080/menu gives me no results, drops a 404 error :/

Comment: @soulzap is this project something personal? If it is you could create a repository on GitHub. That would make it a lot easier to answer

Comment: is there a way I could send you a private message somewhere?